Synchronizing Multiple Devices (VR/MR/PC) with Photon Unity Networking 2 (PUN2)
I'm planning to develop a system using Photon Unity Networking 2 (PUN2).
Is it possible to synchronize multiple devices with PUN2?
The devices I intend to synchronize are as follows:
Meta Quest 3 (VR)
Meta Quest 3 (MR)
Windows PC
Thank you in advance for your help.

Well the whole idea of Photon Networking is to build multi-user synchronized experiences .... so yeah sure it is possible
